# Count SQL Server User Created Functions based on Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, sql-function

I can count total user created functions in SQL Server using

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_type = 'FUNCTION'
```

But this returns all functions whether it be a scalar-valued function, an inline function or a table-valued function

Is there a way to obtain a count specific to the type of function? E.g. count inline functions only?

Comment: `and DATA_TYPE = 'TABLE'` will get you part way there.

Comment: Helpful, I can get the total inline functions and table valued functions then subtract that from the total funtions to get the scalar ones. But is there a way to seperate the table valued and inline ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This distinction you are after is specific to SQL Server and probably not covered by the `information_schema` standard. You need to look at system views for that:

```sql
select o.type_desc, count(*)
from sys.objects o
where o.type in ('AF', 'FN', 'FS', 'FT', 'IF', 'TF')
group by o.type_desc
order by o.type_desc;
```

Depending on the version of SQL Server you are using, the list of available object types might differ. Consult with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql) for your version regarding that.