# SQL query to get the Count of System functions in SQL Server database based on type

Tags: sql, sql-server

How we could get the count of system functions based on type?

In **system functions** we have different type of functions, like "Mathematical", "Aggregate" etc..

In one of the use case I need check the count in an `IF` condition for specific type.

Example:

- Use Case #1: for aggregate type functions, we should get result 15
- Use Case #2: for mathematical type functions, we should get result 23

[image]

I found the quite similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688406/count-sql-server-user-created-functions-based-on-type), but couldn't modify accordingly.

Could someone help me out here?

Thanks!!

Comment: In the link you have referenced, the `o.type` in the where clause of `AF` stands for aggregate function. Try that piece alone and see if it matches the counts you are expecting for your 1st use case.

Comment: Getting no output with AF. I tried-select o.type_desc, count(*)
from sys.objects o
where o.type in ('AF')
group by o.type_desc
order by o.type_desc;